# Grabbing date records that are exactly a month or more away

Tags: mysql, database

I put together a query for determining whether the time difference between the current date and a record from a database is exactly a month or more apart. I am comparing now() to a created_at column, which is a timestamp.

EX:
6-12-2014,
7-12-2014

AND

5-12-2014,
7-12-2014

Should be considered to be a desirable results.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `subscriptions` WHERE 
DATE_ADD(CAST(created_at as DATE),INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, created_at, now()) MONTH)    = CAST(now() as DATE);
```

However the query appears to not return all desired results. It returns 2-28-2014 and 7-28-2014, however it does not pull up 6-28-2014. Is there a better way of doing this than the solution I came up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to count dates that are on the same day of the month as the current date? If so, try the [`DAYOFMONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM subscriptions
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(created_at) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for. Didn't even know about the DAYOFMONTH. I replaced TODAY() with now() because TODAY() apparently isn't a method recognized by MYSQL/PHPMyAdmin(?)

Comment: Oops, I must have been thinking of another database or language with the `TODAY` function; I just checked and it's definitely not a MySQL function. Thanks for letting me know, and I'm glad you figured it out despite my misdirection :) I'll update my answer.